# Get data from fields added by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have added a dynamic number of partial views through jQuery (based on selection of a drop down list).

How to get the data in the text boxes?

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#testStationUniqueId').change(function() {
        var testStation = $(this).val();
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });



        $.ajax({
            url: "TestInput/getTestStationInformation/" + testStation,

            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#driveDetailDiv').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $.post('TestInput/Details/', { id: data[i] }, function(data2) {
                        $('#driveDetailDiv').append(data2);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My partial View has some labels and some text boxes. I don't know how to get value of each text box.

```
    public PartialViewResult Details(string id)
    {
        DriveDetails t = new DriveDetails(id);
        return PartialView("DriveDetailsPartial", t);
    }
```

`DriveDetailsPartial` has some fields and textboxes and dropdown lists, etc.

Comment: texbox in partial view from this request `TestInput/Details/`?

Comment: You mean data2 has all these textboxes that you are talking of?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, after finishing all queries ajax ($.post), in `inputs` you'll have all the `input's` to `driveDetailDiv`:

```
success: function(data) {
   $('#driveDetailDiv').empty();
   var arequest = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      arequest.push($.post('TestInput/Details/', { id: data[i] }, function(data2) {
         $('#driveDetailDiv').append(data2);
      }));
   }

   $.when.apply($, arequest).done(function() {
      var inputs = $('#driveDetailDiv').find('input[type="text"]');
   });​
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andres,
Each PartialView is generated based on a Model, so I was hoping to somehow use  update Model for them. (I need update multiple models)

Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: Where you updated multiple models?, Can you put it in the example. if another question, it would be good that you generate another question.